# Percy not running in CircleCI orbs (w/ Cypress)

Tags: cypress, circleci, orb, percy

I'm trying to get Percy.io to take snapshots of a simple test written in Cypress, building in CircleCI. However, the 'builds' are showing up as failed in the Percy dashboard despite the test/build passing in CircleCI. In the Cypress test runner it is showing 'Percy not running' where my snapshots are placed.

I've followed the tutorials on the Percy and Cypress sites. I can get Percy to work locally, by running *percy exec -- cypress run*
but the CircleCI config doesn't run Cypress via the command *cypress run*, it runs it via the cypress orb.

It seems like the two orbs, Cypress and Percy, doesn't know the other exists.

Here's my CircleCI config file:

```
version: 2.1
orbs:
  node: circleci/node@4.5.1
  cypress: cypress-io/cypress@1.28.0
  slack: circleci/slack@4.4.2
  percy: percy/agent@0.1.3
  

workflows:
  version: 2
  commit-workflow:
    jobs:
      - cypress/run:
          name: Smoke Tests
          record: true
          store_artifacts: true  
          spec: cypress/integration/E2E/*
          post-steps:
            - store_test_results:
                path: test-results
            - slack/notify:
                channel: general
                event: fail
                template: basic_fail_1
                mentions: '@Jac'
            - slack/notify:
                channel: general
                event: pass
                template: basic_success_1
                mentions: '@Jac'   
      - percy/finalize_all:
            requires:
              - Smoke Tests
```

The Run Cypress Tests step doesn't make any mention of Percy, so I'm assuming it simply isn't running - that despite using the Percy orb, there's some sort of config I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Apologies, I keep finding answers to my questions after posting to Stack
Overflow! I obviously don't know the properties of cypress/run well enough. But essentially, there's a custom *command-prefix* property that can be added for the purpose of amending the command used to run cypress. In fact, Percy is the example used in the [Cypress docs](https://circleci.com/developer/orbs/orb/cypress-io/cypress#usage-custom-command-prefix).

Config now looks like:

```
version: 2.1
orbs:
  node: circleci/node@4.5.1
  cypress: cypress-io/cypress@1.28.0
  slack: circleci/slack@4.4.2
  percy: percy/agent@0.1.3
  

workflows:
  version: 2
  commit-workflow:
    jobs:
      - cypress/run:
          name: Smoke Tests
          record: true
          store_artifacts: true  
          spec: cypress/integration/E2E/*
          command-prefix: npx percy exec -- 
          post-steps:
            - store_test_results:
                path: test-results
            - slack/notify:
                channel: general
                event: fail
                template: basic_fail_1
                mentions: '@Jac'
            - slack/notify:
                channel: general
                event: pass
                template: basic_success_1
                mentions: '@Jac'   
      - percy/finalize_all:
            requires:
              - Smoke Tests
```